# New shell window with specified current dir

Tags: bash, shell, gnome-terminal

Now i'm executing next command

```
gnome-terminal  --tab -e "run1"  --tab -e "run2"
```

But run1 and run2 not in my home dir, how can i point shell to right dir. "my_dir1/my_dir2/runX" - not a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual (`man`) is your friend.

`man gnome-terminal` reveals the option

```
--working-directory=DIRNAME
```